# Gentoo emerge Failed for nodejs-20.11.0

Tags: node.js, npm, firefox, gentoo

I am encountering an issue where NodeJs is attempting to utilize SafeMaps before being created.  I am not sure where to continue debugging.

Stackoverflow requirements me to type more: I was trying to install LibreWolf on a brand new Gentoo build that is on VirtualBox.  I have used Gentoo before.  I was able to install several other packages.  Looks like node.js 20.11.0 is LTS.

Here is the entry point:

```
FAILED: gen/node_snapshot.cc 
cd ../../; /var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot /var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/gen/node_snapshot.cc

  #  /var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot[4909]: void node::Realm::CreateProperties() at ../../src/node_realm.cc:72
  #  Assertion failed: ctor->IsObject()

----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x55590cd0d4b0 node::Abort() [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 2: 0x55590cd0d54d  [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 3: 0x55590cd909d4 node::Realm::CreateProperties() [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 4: 0x55590cebd74d node::Environment::InitializeMainContext(v8::Local<v8::Context>, node::EnvSerializeInfo const*) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 5: 0x55590ce63a6e node::CreateEnvironment(node::IsolateData*, v8::Local<v8::Context>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, node::EnvironmentFlags::Flags, node::ThreadId, std::unique_ptr<node::InspectorParentHandle, std::default_delete<node::InspectorParentHandle> >) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 6: 0x55590ce5f871  [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 7: 0x55590ce6093e node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::CommonEnvironmentSetup(node::MultiIsolatePlatform*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*, node::EmbedderSnapshotData const*, unsigned int, std::function<node::Environment* (node::CommonEnvironmentSetup const*)>) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 8: 0x55590ce60db1 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::CreateForSnapshotting(node::MultiIsolatePlatform*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
 9: 0x55590cdbdbe9 node::BuildSnapshotWithoutCodeCache(node::SnapshotData*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::optional<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
10: 0x55590cdbffa3 node::SnapshotBuilder::GenerateAsSource(char const*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::optional<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >, bool) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
11: 0x55590ccc8356 BuildSnapshot(int, char**) [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
12: 0x7f0b2ec4dc8a  [/usr/lib64/libc.so.6]
13: 0x7f0b2ec4dd45 __libc_start_main [/usr/lib64/libc.so.6]
14: 0x55590cb35b91 _start [/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0/out/Release/node_mksnapshot]
[1647/1675] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -MMD -MF obj/test/cctest/cctest.node_test_fixture.o.d -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf -DNODE_OPENSSL_CERT_STORE -DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS '-DNODE_ARCH="x64"' '-DNODE_PLATFORM="linux"' -DNODE_WANT_INTERNALS=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_INSPECTOR=0 -D__POSIX__ -DNODE_USE_V8_PLATFORM=1 -DNODE_V8_SHARED_RO_HEAP -DNODE_HAVE_I18N_SUPPORT=1 -DGTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE=0 -DGTEST_LANG_CXX11=1 -DBASE64_STATIC_DEFINE -DUNIT_TEST -I../../src -I../../tools/msvs/genfiles -I../../deps/v8/include -I../../deps/cares/include -I../../deps/uv/include -I../../deps/uvwasi/include -I../../test/cctest -I../../deps/base64/base64/include -I../../deps/googletest/include -I../../deps/histogram/src -I../../deps/histogram/include -I../../deps/simdutf -I../../deps/ada -I../../deps/llhttp/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=haswell -O2 -pipe -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++17  -c ../../test/cctest/node_test_fixture.cc -o obj/test/cctest/cctest.node_test_fixture.o
[1648/1675] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -MMD -MF obj/test/cctest/cctest.test_aliased_buffer.o.d -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf -DNODE_OPENSSL_CERT_STORE -DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS '-DNODE_ARCH="x64"' '-DNODE_PLATFORM="linux"' -DNODE_WANT_INTERNALS=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_INSPECTOR=0 -D__POSIX__ -DNODE_USE_V8_PLATFORM=1 -DNODE_V8_SHARED_RO_HEAP -DNODE_HAVE_I18N_SUPPORT=1 -DGTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE=0 -DGTEST_LANG_CXX11=1 -DBASE64_STATIC_DEFINE -DUNIT_TEST -I../../src -I../../tools/msvs/genfiles -I../../deps/v8/include -I../../deps/cares/include -I../../deps/uv/include -I../../deps/uvwasi/include -I../../test/cctest -I../../deps/base64/base64/include -I../../deps/googletest/include -I../../deps/histogram/src -I../../deps/histogram/include -I../../deps/simdutf -I../../deps/ada -I../../deps/llhttp/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=haswell -O2 -pipe -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++17  -c ../../test/cctest/test_aliased_buffer.cc -o obj/test/cctest/cctest.test_aliased_buffer.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [Makefile:149: node] Error 1
 * ERROR: net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0/work/node-v20.11.0'
```

The code in question:

```
#define V(EnvPropertyName, PrimordialsPropertyName)                            \
  {                                                                            \
    Local<Value> ctor =                                                        \
        primordials.As<Object>()                                               \
            ->Get(ctx,                                                         \
                  FIXED_ONE_BYTE_STRING(isolate(), PrimordialsPropertyName))   \
            .ToLocalChecked();                                                 \
    CHECK(ctor->IsObject());                                                   \
    Local<Value> prototype =                                                   \
        ctor.As<Object>()->Get(ctx, prototype_string).ToLocalChecked();        \
    CHECK(prototype->IsObject());                                              \
    set_##EnvPropertyName(prototype.As<Object>());                             \
  }

  V(primordials_safe_map_prototype_object, "SafeMap");
```

And here is my build info:

```
shinobi@gentoo ~ $ emerge --info '=net-libs/nodejs-20.11.0::gentoo'
Portage 3.0.61 (python 3.11.8-final-0, default/linux/amd64/17.1/desktop/gnome/systemd/merged-usr, gcc-13, glibc-2.38-r10, 6.6.13-gentoo-dist x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-6.6.13-gentoo-dist-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i7-5820K_CPU_@_3.30GHz-with-glibc2.38
KiB Mem:    16377976 total,  12883772 free
KiB Swap:    4194300 total,   4194300 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Sun, 25 Feb 2024 13:00:00 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: 357d8a8fd0d4c26a3b3a97a40d64f5ccd1a80dba
Head commit of repository librewolf: ff2acece4624decc10ee90cbe70127bc38f7f940

sh bash 5.1_p16-r6
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.41 p5) 2.41.0
app-misc/pax-utils:        1.3.7::gentoo
app-shells/bash:           5.1_p16-r6::gentoo
dev-build/autoconf:        2.13-r8::gentoo, 2.71-r6::gentoo
dev-build/automake:        1.16.5-r2::gentoo
dev-build/cmake:           3.27.9::gentoo
dev-build/libtool:         2.4.7-r2::gentoo
dev-build/make:            4.4.1-r1::gentoo
dev-build/meson:           1.3.1-r1::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:             5.38.2-r1::gentoo
dev-lang/python:           3.11.8_p1::gentoo, 3.12.2_p1::gentoo
dev-lang/rust-bin:         1.74.1::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:       2.14-r2::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:          2.38::gentoo
sys-apps/systemd:          255.3-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:        2.41-r5::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils-config: 5.5::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:             13.2.1_p20240113-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:      2.11::gentoo
sys-devel/llvm:            17.0.6::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers:  6.6::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:            2.38-r10::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /var/db/repos/gentoo
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000
    volatile: False
    sync-rsync-verify-jobs: 1
    sync-rsync-verify-metamanifest: yes
    sync-rsync-verify-max-age: 3
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 

librewolf
    location: /var/db/repos/librewolf
    sync-type: git
    sync-uri: https://codeberg.org/librewolf/gentoo.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50
    volatile: False

Binary Repositories:

gentoobinhost
    priority: 1
    sync-uri: https://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/binpackages/17.1/x86-64

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="@FREE @FREE @BINARY-REDISTRIBUTABLE"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=haswell -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/dconf /etc/env.d /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/sandbox.d"
CXXFLAGS="-march=haswell -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/var/cache/distfiles"
ENV_UNSET="CARGO_HOME DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY GDK_PIXBUF_MODULE_FILE GOBIN GOPATH PERL5LIB PERL5OPT PERLPREFIX PERL_CORE PERL_MB_OPT PERL_MM_OPT XAUTHORITY XDG_CACHE_HOME XDG_CONFIG_HOME XDG_DATA_HOME XDG_RUNTIME_DIR XDG_STATE_HOME"
FCFLAGS="-march=haswell -O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-docompress binpkg-dostrip binpkg-logs binpkg-multi-instance buildpkg-live config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles ipc-sandbox merge-sync multilib-strict network-sandbox news parallel-fetch pid-sandbox pkgdir-index-trusted preserve-libs protect-owned qa-unresolved-soname-deps sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync xattr"
FFLAGS="-march=haswell -O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/     https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/     http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/     rsync://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles     https://gentoo.osuosl.org/     http://gentoo.osuosl.org/"
LANG="C.UTF8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
LEX="flex"
MAKEOPTS="--jobs 3 --load-average 4"
PKGDIR="/var/cache/binpkgs"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
USE="X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cli colord crypt cups dbus dracut dri dts dvd dvdr eds encode evo exif flac fortran gdbm gif gnome gnome-keyring gnome-online-accounts gnome-shell gpm grub gstreamer gtk gui iconv icu introspection ipv6 jpeg keyring lcms libnotify libtirpc mad mesa mng mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib nautilus ncurses networkmanager nls ogg opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf png policykit ppds pulseaudio readline sdl seccomp sound spell ssl startup-notification svg sysprof systemd test-rust tiff tracker truetype udev udisks unicode upower usb vorbis vulkan wayland wxwidgets x264 xattr xcb xft xml xv xvid zlib" ABI_X86="64" ADA_TARGET="gnat_2021" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_anon authn_dbm authn_file authz_dbm authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon sheets words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2 aes avx avx2 pclmul popcnt rdrand sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock greis isync itrax mtk3301 ntrip navcom oceanserver oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 tsip tripmate tnt ublox" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb text" LUA_SINGLE_TARGET="lua5-1" LUA_TARGETS="lua5-1" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php8-1" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres15" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_11" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_11" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby31" VIDEO_CARDS="vmware" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tarpit sysrq proto logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  ADDR2LINE, AR, ARFLAGS, AS, ASFLAGS, CC, CCLD, CONFIG_SHELL, CPP, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, CXXFILT, ELFEDIT, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, EXTRA_ECONF, F77FLAGS, FC, GCOV, GPROF, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, LD, LFLAGS, LIBTOOL, LINGUAS, MAKE, MAKEFLAGS, NM, OBJCOPY, OBJDUMP, PORTAGE_BINHOST, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, PYTHONPATH, RANLIB, READELF, RUSTFLAGS, SIZE, STRINGS, STRIP, YACC, YFLAGS
```